# In SAP Web IDE how to use JSON only mock data without metadata.xml

Tags: sapui5

In SAP Web IDE I'm trying to use the layout editor to create a view. My project uses a JSON model, not an oData model.

In layout editor, view properties, "data set" - is there a way to directly assign a JSON file to be used as a source for mock data **without** having the metadata.xml file around?

Currently the "data set" dropdown menu is only filled if there is the metadata.xml file present in the right location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load the data in **onInit** event function in the controller of the your view. Sample code:

```
    onInit: function(){

        var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("yourProjectName.folderWhereYouHaveTheJsonFile","/jsonFile.json"));
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },
```

About "**yourProjectName.folderWhereYouHaveTheJsonFile**", if your project name is "**Xpto**", and you have the JSON file (named **products.json**) located in "**model**" folder, the first line will be:

```
var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("Xpto.model","/products.json"));
```

Comment: that's what I call insider knowledge. Thanks a million